# How to calculate special characters in a text file in python?

Tags: python

I want to calculate the number of non-alphanumeric characters in a text file, so that I can use that count as a feature in my feature set for text classification.
Any help would be greatly helpful.

Comment: What are special characters? Give a definition, pls.

Comment: characters like , : ; " ' ? / > < { [ ) * &

Comment: When you say "characters like `, : ; " ' ? / > < { [ ) * &` ", do you mean exactly that set of characters, or some broader set of characters we're supposed to deduce from those examples?

Comment: All characters except alphabets and numeric.

Comment: Do you want  a count **per** character, or the total amount?

Comment: I want total amount. :)

Comment: @kapil: are new lines (`'\n'`) also considered special characters? What about spaces, tabs,...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes all included. ALL Special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the file and use the [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) method to count the number of non-alphanumerical characters.

So something like:

```
count_special = 0
with open(filename,mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count_special += sum(not x.isalnum() for x in line)
print(count_special)
```

So after the loop, the `count_special` contains the total number of non-alphanumerical characters.

By parsing one line at a time, this method will usually be able to process large text files, since it does not have to load the entire file into memory first.

Comment: Thanks @Willem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way. You have to define list of special characters as `regex`:

```
import re
x = re.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]") 
# also you can use "[^\w]" or "[\W]" patterns
```

And find number of special characters as a length of `re.findall`:

```
s = ", : ; \" ' ? / > < { [ ) * & \n"
print len(re.findall(x, s))
29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string method "isalnum" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) which return False if string contain non-alphanumeric characters.

```
>>> "Egg".isalnum()
>>> True
>>> "[".isalnum()
>>> False
>>> "-Spam-".isalnum()
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the number of non alpha numeric chacacters in a file:

```
def count_non_alphanumeric(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f: #open the file as f
        nonalpha_count=0           # this is the running count of alphanumeric chars
        for line in f: #for each line in the file...
            for ch in line:  #for each character in the line...
                if not ch.isalnum():  # check to see if the character is alphanumeric
                    nonalpha_count+=1
    return nonalpha_count
```